# Has Many mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, relationship, has-many

I have a DB with users table and an answers table. Each user has 30 answers. I want to export a user and all their answers on a single row.

e.g:

```
ID  | email   | answer_1 | answer_2 | answer_3 | etc...
----|---------|----------|----------|----------|--------
1   | e@g.com |  foo     | bar      | baz      | ....
```

I currently have

```
SELECT *
    FROM users
    LEFT JOIN answers AS A 
        ON users.id = A.user_id
    WHERE email IS NOT NULL
```

This creates a 30 rows for each user with their answer against each one. How can I group this into one row per user with a column for each answer?

Comment: Please show us the table structure for the `answers` table.

Comment: Normalise your design. A database table is NOT a spreadsheet

Comment: @Strawberry you're correct but I need to export this as a CSV so I can then provide it as a spreadsheet. Hence why it needs to be in the required format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using a pivot query, something like this:

```
SELECT uid, email,
       MAX(CASE WHEN a.aid = 1 THEN a.answer END) AS answer_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN a.aid = 2 THEN a.answer END) AS answer_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN a.aid = 3 THEN a.answer END) AS answer_3
       -- add more CASE expressions to cover all 30 answers
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN answers a
    ON u.id = a.user_id
WHERE u.email IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY u.id, u.email
```

Assumptions: The `answers` table has an id column identifying and numbering each of the 30 answers.  Without this, the query could be a real pain.  I also assume that each user will have exactly 30 answers.  Missing answers would show up as `NULL` in the case where they are not present.